# View remote value of $PATH inside shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, quoting, here-document

When executing this bash script, it only shows my local path.

```
ssh ${REMOTE_HOST} 'bash -s' <<EOL
    set -e
    source ~/.profile
    echo $PATH
    # Commands here don't work because $PATH is not set properly.
    # How can I see what $PATH is set to here?
EOL
```

How can I view the remote value of `$PATH` to debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$PATH` is getting expanded prior to running on the remote server.

#### Example #1

Say I run these commands from a system called skinner.bubba.net.

```
[root@skinner ~]# ssh mulder 'bash -s' <<EOL
>   echo $HOSTNAME
>   hostname
> EOL
skinner.bubba.net
mulder.bubba.net
```

By moving the single quote so that the `echo $HOSTNAME` is inside it, you can guard the variable from getting expanded by skinner's Bash shell.

```
[root@skinner ~]# ssh mulder 'bash -s <<EOL
>   echo $HOSTNAME
>   hostname
> EOL'
mulder.bubba.net
mulder.bubba.net
```

#### Example #2

The other method would be to escape the `$HOSTNAME` with a slash, which tells Bash you want to send a literal dollar sign.

```
[root@skinner ~]# ssh mulder 'bash -s' <<EOL
>   echo \$HOSTNAME
>   hostname
> EOL
mulder.bubba.net
mulder.bubba.net
```