# Redirecting an output of a subshell to a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh, scripting

I'm trying to execute a script in SSH, and pass some params to that script. I've tried the following which didn't work - the value is not passed:

```
$ LC_FOO=x ssh -o SendEnv=LC_FOO $HOST < myLongScript.sh
```

The target hosts are sometimes very strict and recreated regularly so changing SSH settings on them is futile.

So I'm trying to resort to a trick and pass the value within the script itself. In other words, I want to append the variables to the script.

I've also tried these other approaches:

```
# doesn't work - 'ambiguous redirect'
$ ssh ... < $(...)

# doesn't work - 'LC_FOO=x: command not found'
$ $(echo "FOO=x"; cat myLongScript.sh) | ssh ...
```

How can I prepend the line on `ssh`'s input?

Comment: `LC_FOO=x ssh -o SendEnv=LC_FOO` should have worked I think - provided the server side's `AcceptEnv` is set appropriately of course. Did you try something simple like `LC_FOO=x ssh -o SendEnv=LC_FOO user@remotehost 'printenv LC_FOO'`?

Comment: @slm on my Ubuntu/OpenSSH boxes, the (default) `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` have `SendEnv LC_*` and `AcceptEnv LC_*` respectively so actually for me it wasn't even necessary to add the `-o SendEnv=LC_FOO`

Comment: @steeldriver - interesting, this was on CentOS 6/7 systems, confirmed like you said on a Ubuntu 16.04 box I have here.

Comment: The script connects to different systems and are very strict. "hardened" CentOS mostly. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You want a [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) such as `ssh ... < <(...)`. `ssh ... < $(my_command)` is a [command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) creates a redirect with each [word](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) from the result of `my_command` as the redirect target.

Answer (score 1):

The first example will work if you enable the variable `LC_FOO` so that it's on the `AcceptEnv` list on the server side's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

```
$ grep AcceptEnv /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
AcceptEnv LC_FOO
```

Now it works:

```
$ LC_FOO=x ssh -o SendEnv=LC_FOO root@host.mydom.com 'printenv LC_FOO'
x
```

#### Alternatives

***redirect method***

I've shown this in another U&L Q&A titled: [How can I execute local script on remote machine and include arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments/87406#87406), and for your example I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" -- < ./ex.bash "arg1" "arg2"
```

***heredoc method***

You could also do a heredoc style as well which I highlighted in this other U&L Q&A titled: [View remote value of $PATH inside shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213676/view-remote-value-of-path-inside-shell-script/213679#213679):

```
[root@skinner ~]# ssh mulder 'bash -s <<EOL
>   echo $HOSTNAME
>   hostname
> EOL'
mulder.bubba.net
mulder.bubba.net
```

#### References

- [How can I execute local script on remote machine and include arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments/87406#87406)
- [View remote value of $PATH inside shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213676/view-remote-value-of-path-inside-shell-script/213679#213679)